# Puppeteer: Override API Requests and respond with mock data without another package

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, playwright

I am trying to get mock data for puppeteer for a dynamic vue application.

Here is what I have (with placeholder API urls):

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true)
    page.on('request', (request) => {
      console.log(request.url())
      if (request.url() === 'URL HERE') {
        request.respond({
          status: 200,
          content: 'application/json',
          body: JSON.stringify(MockData.image)
        })
      } else if (request.url() === 'URL HERE') {
        request.respond({
          status: 200,
          content: 'application/json',
          body: JSON.stringify(MockData.text)
        })
      } else {
        request.continue()
      }
    })
```

This snippet sits above all logic where the requests would come through, and the URLS are correct.

The mocked calls do not seem to finish or come through correctly. Is this a problem with my setup?

Comment: What are the visible sympthoms of the issue if you launch puppeteer with headful browser and devtools opened? Are the mocked responses pending until the script timeouts? Or do you have partial success for some requests?

Comment: Thanks for this. Requests seem to timeout. Even if mocked data is same as original.

Comment: Scratch that. Some requests can be overridden while others timeout

Comment: Your script looks correct, however: are you sure the 'URL HERE' values are 100% matching? It is safer to use `if (request.url().includes('URL UNIQUE PART HERE')) {...` However I had pages where I was unable to make mocking with `setRequestInterception` work. I suspect it is heavily dependent on how the service workers are implemented, if there are some hidden errors in the background there can be issues during mocking.

Comment: Solved. Was cors related! Thanks for the tips

Comment: Good to hear, nice job Sean! Can you post the solution below as an independent answer? E.g. what setting, code change or extra flag helped to avoid the cors issue. It can be super helpful for others as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was to call launch with chromium security disabled.

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: ['--disable-web-security']
})
```